# How to make a batch by grouping parts differently for each model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two data frames.
The first data frame is information about the (df1) model and two parts.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
                'p1':['p1_1','p1_1','p1_2','p1_2','p1_3','p1_4', 'p1_4','p1_5','p1_6','p1_7'],
                'p2':['p2_1','p2_1','p2_1','p2_2','p2_3', 'p2_4', 'p2_5', 'p2_6', 'p2_7','p2_7']})
```

[image]

Depending on the model, the reference part is different. about this
The information is the second data frame (df2).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','B'],
                    'part':['p1','p2']})
```

Model A is based on p1, and model B is based on p2.

Replace the detailed description with the figure below.

[image]

The dataframe above is the desired output.

Comment: Is `model` column ordered in your actual dataframe?

Comment: No, it is only my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt your first dataframe then merge with the second one to create a `batch` column:

```
df1['batch'] = (
    df1.melt('model', var_name='part', value_name='batch', ignore_index=False)
       .reset_index().merge(df2, on=['model', 'part']).set_index('index')['batch']
)
print(df1)

# Output
  model    p1    p2 batch
0     A  p1_1  p2_1  p1_1
1     A  p1_1  p2_1  p1_1
2     A  p1_2  p2_1  p1_2
3     A  p1_2  p2_2  p1_2
4     A  p1_3  p2_3  p1_3
5     B  p1_4  p2_4  p2_4
6     B  p1_4  p2_5  p2_5
7     B  p1_5  p2_6  p2_6
8     B  p1_6  p2_7  p2_7
9     B  p1_7  p2_7  p2_7
```

Now you can group by model and batch columns:

```
>>> list(df1.groupby(['model', 'batch']))

[(('A', 'p1_1'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  0     A  p1_1  p2_1  p1_1
  1     A  p1_1  p2_1  p1_1),
 (('A', 'p1_2'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  2     A  p1_2  p2_1  p1_2
  3     A  p1_2  p2_2  p1_2),
 (('A', 'p1_3'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  4     A  p1_3  p2_3  p1_3),
 (('B', 'p2_4'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  5     B  p1_4  p2_4  p2_4),
 (('B', 'p2_5'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  6     B  p1_4  p2_5  p2_5),
 (('B', 'p2_6'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  7     B  p1_5  p2_6  p2_6),
 (('B', 'p2_7'),
    model    p1    p2 batch
  8     B  p1_6  p2_7  p2_7
  9     B  p1_7  p2_7  p2_7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The second dataframe `df2` can be converted to `model : part` mapping and used for filtering/constructing separate dataframes:

```
model_map = dict(df2.to_dict('split')['data'])  # model/part mapping
df = pd.concat([df1[df1.model.eq(k)]
               .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(batch=x[v].str.replace(v, 'batch')))
                for k, v in model_map.items()])
```

---

```
  model    p1    p2    batch
0     A  p1_1  p2_1  batch_1
1     A  p1_1  p2_1  batch_1
2     A  p1_2  p2_1  batch_2
3     A  p1_2  p2_2  batch_2
4     A  p1_3  p2_3  batch_3
5     B  p1_4  p2_4  batch_4
6     B  p1_4  p2_5  batch_5
7     B  p1_5  p2_6  batch_6
8     B  p1_6  p2_7  batch_7
9     B  p1_7  p2_7  batch_7
```

Comment: It works fine. I learned a lot. Thank you.